# Get commit sha of specific branch in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that is building code from a specific branch.

The workflow is currently run manually by developers. They enter the branch they want to build.

I want to print the latest commit SHA of the specific chosen branch, when the workflow is run, **as part of the `run-name:`**

This code works only for the `master` branch. It always displays the **SHA of the latest commit in the `master` branch.** If you specify a different branch it still shows the same commit SHA from the `master` branch.

```
run-name: Build from [Branch = ${{ inputs.branch }}] && [COMMIT SHA = ${{ github.sha }}]
```

Is there a different github variable (or some other method) I can use to get the SHA of the latest commit in the specific chosen branch **as part of the `run-name:`**.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Actions does not allow dynamic assignment of `run-name:` within the workflow YAML file based on the runtime environment variables or calculated values. The `run-name:` is statically defined when the workflow is loaded, and it cannot be modified during the workflow execution.

That limitation means that the latest commit SHA of a dynamically chosen branch cannot be incorporated into the `run-name:` field during the workflow's runtime. GitHub Actions lacks native support for this kind of dynamic behavior for the `run-name:` field.

You can still print the commit SHA in the logs or use other methods to inform the developers, but it will not appear in the `run-name:` as you specifically required. The dynamic aspects are generally confined to the `steps:` or `jobs:` sections of the workflow.

---

In GitHub Actions, [`${{ github.sha }}`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts) indeed provides the commit SHA that triggered the workflow. However, when you are specifying a different branch manually, it does not automatically fetch the latest SHA from that branch.

To get the latest commit SHA of a specific branch, you will need to use Git commands to fetch the latest SHA from that branch before setting it as an environment variable, which you can then reference in the `run-name`.

```yaml
name: Get Latest Commit SHA

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      branch:
        description: 'Branch to build'
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get latest commit SHA
        run: |
          git fetch origin ${{ github.event.inputs.branch }}
          echo "COMMIT_SHA=$(git rev-parse origin/${{ github.event.inputs.branch }})" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Build and Print
        run: echo "Build from [Branch = ${{ github.event.inputs.branch }}] && [COMMIT SHA = $COMMIT_SHA]"
```

- In the "Get latest commit SHA" step, we use the `git fetch` command to fetch the latest data from the specified branch.
- We then use `git rev-parse` to get the latest commit SHA from the specified branch, and store it in an environment variable called `COMMIT_SHA`.
- In the "Build and Print" step, we reference the `COMMIT_SHA` environment variable to print the branch name and the commit SHA as part of the run name.

Do replace the echo command in "`Build and Print`" step with your actual build process, keeping the `run-name` parameter intact with the specified structure to include both branch name and commit SHA.

Comment: I specifically mentioned `run-name:` not `run:`
I want the commit sha to appear as part of the workflow name in the workflow executions. I don't think this is possible at the moment in GitHub.

Comment: @Subzero123 I understand. I have edited the answer to clearly mention this is not supported. I will leave the original answer as a possible workaround.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Have a nice day.